# Which of the Gauss-Markov assumptions does error-in-variables violate?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, inference

The Gauss-Markov theorem states that for a linear model

$$y = X \beta + \epsilon $$

if both of the conditions are true

$$\operatorname E[\epsilon \mid X] = 0$$
$$\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon) = \sigma^2 I < \infty $$

then the standard OLS estimator $(X'X)^{-1}X'y$ is the best linear unbiased estimator.

Now suppose we measure $X$ with errors. Then we have

$$y = (X + \mu)\beta  + \epsilon = X\beta + \mu\beta+\epsilon$$

If $\mu$ is of mean $0$ with constant variance, both assumptions still hold. Why then is the OLS estimator biased?

Comment: I would say the OLS estimator is $(X'X)^{-1}X'y,$ not just $(X'X)^{-1}X'.$ In particular, the form $(X'X)^{-1}X'y$ shows you why the word "linear" is used: It's linear as a function of $y. \qquad$

Comment: $(X'X)^{-1} X' y$ is still the best linear unbiased estimator. $((X+\mu)'(X+\mu))^{-1}(X+\mu)' y$ is not.

Comment: Let $z = x + u$. If you rewrite in terms of observable $z$, your problem is $\operatorname{E}[u \mid z] \neq 0$

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No, I thought that noise in the independent variables shouldn't bias the coefficients if it's independent but everything I've read online told me otherwise. Couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the true data generating process is:
$$ y_i = x_i \beta + \epsilon_i $$
But we don't observe $x_i$, instead we observe $ z_i = x_i + u_i$. We can write the above using observables ($z_i, y_i$): 
$$ y_i = z_i \beta + v_i $$
Where the error term is $ v_i = \epsilon_i - \beta u_i$. Is the strict exogeneity requirement $\operatorname{E}[v \mid z] = 0$ satisfied? No.

- If $\operatorname{E}[v \mid z] = 0$ then $\operatorname{E}[vz]=0$, but $\operatorname{E}[vz]=\operatorname{E}[(\epsilon - \beta u)(x + u)] = - \beta \operatorname{E}[u^2] $. $\bot$

The underlying cause is that $\operatorname{E}[u \mid x + u] \neq 0$. The precise story depends on the distribution of $x$ and $u$, but loosely speaking, above average measurements $z$ are going to be associated with positive measurement error $u$.